# Java padrão de design para reutilização de código

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Eu estou desenvolvendo um programa simples em `Java` Desktop usando `SqLite` para armazenar dados locais, gostaria de saber qual padrão de design eu posso usar para reutilizar os códigos `Java` para desenvolver o mesmo aplicativo para `Android`, no meu projeto eu estou usando o padrão `MVC`.

Este é o mais apropriado para esta situação?

Tenho um conhecimento intermediariamente em Java para Android, Ciclo de Activitys, Views, BaseAdapter, Handlers, AsyncTask, persistência com sqlite e etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não existe um padrão absolutamente melhor que os demais.

O conceito de MVC ajuda, mas é só um começo. O reuso do código vai depender do nível de acoplamento do seu código. É possível escrever código MVC tão interdependente que não se consegue reaproveitar uma única classe, assim como não usar nenhum padrão de alto nível e escrever classes altamente reusáveis.

Raciocine em termos de **[coesão](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/cc947917.aspx)** e **[acoplamento](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoplamento_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_computadores%29)**. Resumidamente, a coesão é o nível de clareza da função de uma classe e acoplamento é o nível de dependência de uma classe em relação às demais.

Você deve codificar almejando alta coesão, isto é, classes com responsabilidades bem definidas. Também deve buscar baixo acoplamento, isto é, evitar que uma classe dependa diretamente de muitas outras.

Existem várias técnicas e princípios para alcançar esses objetivos. Por exemplo:

- Cada método deve executar apenas uma ação significativa. Se houver operações complexas, elas devem ser distribuídas para outros métodos. O "algoritmo" de cada método deve ser claro e perceptível.
- Uma classe só deve conter os métodos que fazem sentido a ela. Além disso, uma classe deve ter uma única responsabilidade. É comum implementações de classes que misturam conceitos, por exemplo, uma classe que faz cálculos com datas e também é responsável por formatá-las. Então quando for necessário reusar a parte de cálculos, você acaba tendo que levar a formatação junto, o que pode não ser desejado. Este é o **princípio da responsabilidade única**.
- Ao criar APIs para reuso, faça com que suas classes dependam apenas de interfaces ao invés de implementações concretas, pois dessa forma será possível substituir uma das implementações sempre que necessário.
- Use **Inversão de Controle** e **Injeção de Dependência** para evitar depender de outras classes diretamente. Se você tem uma classe `A` que usa um método da classe `B`, não faça um `new B()` diretamente dentro da classe `A`. Faça com que `A` receba uma instância de `B`, por exemplo, no construtor. E também faça com que `B` seja uma interface. Dessa forma, ao criar `A`, você pode passar a implementação adequada de `B`.

[SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) é um conjunto de conceitos de *design* de classes que pode ajudar ainda mais. Ele começa pelo Princípio da Responsabilidade Única e inclui mais quatro conceitos importantes. Não irei detalhar todos aqui, mas vale a pena estudar cada um.

Enfim, existem várias técnicas e princípios para criar classes reutilizáveis. Algumas são um pouco complicadas de entender.

A verdade é que ninguém tem uma resposta definitiva para isso. A experiência ajuda, mas deve-se levar em conta que **escrever código para reuso é sempre mais difícil**.

Brooks escreve no livro *The Mythical Man-Month* que a ordem de dificuldade para fazer um programa "caseiro" (que roda apenas em uma máquina e faz algo específico) se tornar algo reutilizável é de nove vezes. Na prática, isso significa que você vai ter quase dez vezes o trabalho para criar uma biblioteca em comparação com criar rotinas específicas para um projeto.

A questão para definir se o código deve ser implementado de forma reutilizável é se o mesmo é importante o suficiente para isso.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta @utluiz tenho um pouco de conhecimento em DI e SOLID optei pelo padrão MVC pela forma como a View é separada e sabemos que a construção da interface gráfica para Java desktop com Swing é um tanto diferente da usada pelo Java Android que é a base de XMl, sem contar que o Android possui particularidades como ter na maioria das vezes que usar Threads com AsyncTask

Comment: No final das contas meu objetivo é conseguir extrair toda logica de negocio e a persistência dos dados para um projeto Android e implementar apenas as Views, considerei utilizar um Framework de DI para isso, me recomendaram Spring Framework oque você acha ?

Comment: @Tuyoshi Infelizmente acho que você não vai conseguir isso tão facilmente. Embora exista uma versão do Spring para Android, é apenas um módulo e não o framework todo. Além disso, a persistência em mobile é muito diferente da usada em aplicações web ou locais, então provavelmente você vai ter que escrever código específico. Use uma interface de persistências com duas implementações diferentes para Android e Desktop, isso evitará você precisar modificar outras classes.

Comment: @Tuyoshi Se o seu projeto é simples, não  precisa de um framework de DI, apenas declare as dependências de cada classe no construtor e passe as referências na hora de instanciar.

Comment: já trabalhei com persistência com  sqlite em android é possivel que mude muito em relação a sqlite pra desktop?

Comment: @Tuyoshi Não sei responder com exatidão. Nunca trabalhei com SQlite. Sugiro criar outra pergunta no site especificamente sobre a possibilidade de criar um mesmo código SQLite para web e desktop.

Comment: o programa desktop inicialmente trabalhará com SQLite local futuramente eu faria um sincronismo com algum banco remoto tipo MySql mas inicialmente seria SQLite Local, o programa é simples é um gerenciador de finanças pessoais.(Sem querer fugir do assunto rsrs Acho que o SOpt tem algum bug quando eu coloco seu nick(@utluiz) na primeira posição da primeira linha do comentário o sistema remove, muito estranho )